# khotkey script calling bindings stop to work on switching to Quantal

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu

I have many scripts which I call with khotkey. For example I have a hotkey which executes:

```
bk_starts_or_brings.bash 'Konsole' konsole
```

On updating to Quantal -- it stops to work: if I call that key -- it searches

```
bk_starts_or_brings.bash 'Konsole' konsole
```

in google in default web-browser.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases fakeroot libqtgui4
```

When I start the command from konsole -- it works as expected, but when I call it with khotkey -- it doesn't. I guess someone shadows my keybiding. Or some daemon is not run on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I solved it:

```
sudo apt-get install kdm kde-standard
```

Comment: I also had to install `kdm` on updating to Raring.